# PHP add code to new object

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a question about php.

I was wondering how can i add this code to a new object so i can later just add it to existing code and use it.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "kooliasi");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf ("System status: %s\n", $mysqli->stat());

$mysqli->close();


?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: make one `db.php` file and put this code inside it. Later wherever you want to perform db operations just include this file as `include_once("db.php");`

Comment: @Marko Paju - did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class for the connection:

```
class Database{
private static $link = null ;

public static function getConnection ( ) {
    if (self :: $link) {
        return self :: $link;
    }

    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=social_network;host=localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "pass";

    self :: $link = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); //OR mysqli - matter of preference
    return self :: $link;
}
```

}

Then you can get the connection like this:

```
Database::getConnection();
```

This is a Singleton Pattern. You could use this if you like, but it is hard to scale - However, I think it will be fine for your needs. It takes a lot of load off your database.

There is a php.ini setting for prepending a file to every script -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: @MarkoPaju - Create a new .php File. Paste the class in there. Then include this in the script you need the connection. Then you can do $db_connection = Database::get_connection();$db_connection->query();

Comment: @MarkoPaju Please Mark as correct if this solved your problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a db class where you can keep the connection handle. Add functions to the class as needed. For example

```
class db{
    private $link;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->link);
    }

    public function query($q){
        ... add code here for the query
    }

}
```

Then to use the class you call:

```
$db = new db();
$db->query($parameters_you_want_to_pass);
```